# html5 / css3 page-break-* not working correctly in chrome or safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, safari, page-break

So I've got the following CSS.

```
#container { margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 800px; }

.print { display: none; }

@media print {
  #container { margin: 0; page-break-before: always; }
  .print { display: block; }
}
```

Applied to the following HTML.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div class="print">
      <img src="/logo" style="left: 50%; margin-left: -34px; margin-top: -15px; position: absolute; top: 50%;" />
    </div>

    <div id="container">
      <div>

        ...

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And everything is wonderful except in Chrome and in Safari, which both insert a page-break **before** `<img>` and stick `/logo` right smack in the middle of page 2. I get the same putting (for example) `page-break-after: always;` in the print class. I suspect this might have something to do with `position: absolute;`?

How can I get `<div class="print">` to show up in page 1, with `/logo` in the middle, and `<div id="container">` to start at the top of page 2?

Comment: I cannot manage to get the code above to replicate what is happening in production. And I cannot manage to strip production code in any intelligible way to make it replicate the above (working) code.
Anyway, it seems that modifying the `img style` attribute fixes both chrome and safari, although I am not sure why. Here's what I'm using now:  

    `<div style="text-align:center;"><img style="position:relative; top:210px;" /></div>`